# React, react-router useHistory. Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I only have one copy of React, checked it with `npm ls react`, react and react-dom are the same version and I'm not breaking any of the hook rules right? I don't know what to do any more.

```
ERROR: Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

My component:

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function HomeButton() {
    let history = useHistory();

    function handleClick() {
     history.push("/home");
    }

    return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
    );
}
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1"
},
```

Comment: How are you rendering `HomeButton`?

Comment: in App.js. I ran npm ls react agian, and notice that I got the following                      
 └── react@16.12.0. So i guess it is two versions then, any solutions?

Comment: now I ran this from the react docs and received true, which mean there is not two versions of react: // Add this in node_modules/react-dom/index.js
window.React1 = require('react');

// Add this in your component file
require('react-dom');
window.React2 = require('react');
console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);

Comment: Are you sure this is the only place your using react hooks in the application?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it,
added in webpack.config.js under resolve the following:

```
 alias: {
        react: path.resolve("./node_modules/react"),
        }
```

I use create-react-app, so I had to run npm run eject, which is not recommended. Anyone got a better idé for the future?

Comment: I'm using create-react-app too. I tried your solution and it didn't work.